# Suggested edit was edited, but I think that's a mistake

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

I've edited this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388190/numpy-2d-and-1d-addition-flat) and formatted the code inside the question. Then someone (on the suggested-edit-queue) re-edited the error message to its original form. I don't think that is helping readability. Readability is something subjective and maybe the editor of my edit has a point in reverting it.

Well, what should I do now? Leave it or re-edit it?

Comment: I made an edit to preserve the newline lost by quote markdown. Beyond that, meh.

Comment: The problem with a code block is that you get code formatting, which doesn't always look reasonable for error messages. The alternative is to explicitly disable code formatting with a comment, or to use a blockquote. Here a blockquote seems eminently reasonable. Remember that to force a new line in Markdown, you put *two* spaces at the end of the previous line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no rule about formatting error/log messages; what should be done is what looks better. If the spacing, tabs, new lines, etc.. are important and for readability and clarity, then a code block formation will be better.

I think you shouldn't waste your time about that, just leave it as is and move on to the next edit, that newline is not really a big deal.

---

If we were looking for example at a Java stack trace, then it's very clear that

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example....
        at com.example....
        at com.example....
```

looks much better than

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)
>           at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookTitles(Author.java:25)
>           at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)